focus-converter fails for AWS_CUR parquet file missing 'bill_invoicing_entity'
We are trying to use focus-converter to convert billing data files from popular public cloud providers, such as Amazon Web Services into the common schema known as FOCUS.
You can read about focus-converter here.
We are using AWS Cost and Usage Report(CUR) which is in parquet format and using the following command for conversion.

focus-converter convert --provider aws --data-path
/home/focus/aws_cur/aws-plaform-001.snappy.parquet --data-format
parquet --parquet-data-format dataset --export-path /tmp/

We are getting the following error

ValueError: Column(s) 'bill_invoicing_entity' not found in data

Well the error seems self explanatory, but we are not sure

How we can add this field in Cost and Usage report?
Can we convert the file even without this field in the report?

